# How to typeset imperial/US customary units, especially in combination with SI/metric units

Tags: units

I am just working on a document (a series of exercises for one of my classes), which uses both the SI and US customary unit systems (different exercises use different systems).  I am trying to typeset the units in a consistent way.  I am using the excellent `siunitx` package, and add the US units manually, however, it feels sort of strange to write things like `\DeclareSIUnit\inch{in}`. Does anybody have any good way of handling a situation like this?

(I could just use ConTeXt, but I want to take advantage of the `beamer` class.)

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with the command names, why not `\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit` and `\let\US\SI` and then you can declare and typset the US units with those commands.  We can call this the therapeutic solution. :-)

Comment: @AlanMunn: I like that! :)

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the only real problem with the `siunitx` solution is the clash of names, it's simple enough to just create duplicate versions of the `siunitx` commands so that the semantics match the content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\inch{in}
\begin{document}

\US{1}{\inch} is \SI{2.54}{\cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, I have done that, and I feel much better now!  Thank you.

Comment: It's called `\DeclareSIUnit` because `\DeclareUnit` is too generic (`biblatex` also uses 'units'), not to put people off creating non-standard units :-)

Comment: But I still have to declare every English unit I want to use. Is there no package with the US system?

Comment: @Jeff - The package is called `siunitx` for a reason...