# Using units in latex

Tags: units

I am preparing a document where I have to use SI units and US Customary units, Yet I have 2 issues:

- I can use siunitx package to insert SI units, but what package can I use to insert US Customary units in a similar manner?
- siunitx package insert only the abbreviated form of the unit, for example kilogram is inserted as kg, is there a way to insert the full description of the units?

Comment: On the first part, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42087/how-to-typeset-imperial-us-customary-units-especially-in-combination-with-si-me

Comment: On the second part, unit symbols are not abbreviations: the `siunitx` package is about typesetting in mathematical contexts, not writing out 'in words'. There are various acronym/glossary packages one could use if you want to have the 'full text' available.

Comment: There are several questions on defining new units, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/defining-new-unit-year-century-in-siunitx/6018#6018

Comment: @ Joseph, all solutions regarding US customary units rely on defining the units. Is there a package, an available options which provides a systematic approach for the use of the US customary units as in siunitx?

Comment: @Joseph, regarding using the FULL text of the units, can you help me out by mentioning some packages?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no pre-constructed list of US customary or avoirdupois units in a (La)TeX package. Setting them up is pretty trivial ...

Comment: @JosephWright, regarding the use of the full text for the unit, is it ok if  insert it as (for example) \si{kilogram} instead of \si{\kilogram}, it inserts the full text since I omitted the backslash before the unit inside the braces?